# Как избавиться от кеширования контента модального окна Bootstrap 2.3.2

Tags: bootstrap

Имеется стандартное модальное окно `Bootstrap 2.3.2`.
Оно запускается через `Data API`.

Код ссылки при клике на которой идет запуск модального окна.

```
<a 
href="/ajax.php?task=city_modal&amp;region=by&amp;rand=0.46261814205991447" 
class="btn-link openModal pload" 
id="CityLink"
data-toggle="modal"
data-target="#CityModal"
data-elm="City"
data-remote="/ajax.php?task=city_modal&amp;region=by&amp;rand=0.46261814205991447"
data-baseurl="/ajax.php?task=city_modal">
<i class="icon-plus-sign"></i> ВЫБРАТЬ ГОРОД
```

Как наверно всем понятно, в виде попытки решить проблему кеширования, при смене родительского региона, в ссылке меняется часть `URL` а именно параметр rand и параметр `region` так же меняется. То есть ссылка все время разная, как в атрибуте `href` так и в `data-remote`.

В итоге, иногда это решение работает а иногда нет.
Я вот думаю что эти костыли тут не к месту и создатели Bootstrap не настолько глупы чтобы не справиться с этой проблемой "из коробки". Может как проще это можно решить? Да и вообще решить...

> Атрибут `data-baseurl` добавлен мной для того чтобы скрипт брал базовый `URL` и на основе его собирал новое значение для атрибутов `href` и `data-remote`
>
> Google Chrome Версия 53.0.2785.143 m

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Вопрос актуален для широкий аудитории. На все поднимаемые вопросы
>   необходимо давать подробный и четкий ответ.

Ну раз вопрос актуален для широкой аудитории, то и ответ нужно давать для максимально широкой аудитории.

Чтобы отгрузить данные модального окна при его закрытии, в Bootstrap 2.x можно использовать следующее:

```
$('#CityModal').on('hidden', function() {
    $(this).removeData('modal');
});
```

А в Bootstrap 3 это выглядело бы вот так (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/7935#issuecomment-18513516):

```
$(document.body).on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    $('#CityModal').removeData('bs.modal')
});

// Ну и более универсальный вариант
$(document).on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
    $(e.target).removeData('bs.modal');
});
```

Взято отсюда https://stackoverflow.com/a/18459248/5381547

Comment: Увы то что взято оттуда ) я все перепробовал... и тут тоже промах, не работает оно!

Comment: Еще раз повторяю это не верный ответ!!!

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно разрушать объект модального окна после каждого закрытия:

```
$('body').on('hidden.bs.modal', '.modal', function () {
  $(this).removeData('bs.modal');
});
```

## Реализация

Пример реализации здесь: [**Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/yMofRZ?p=preview)

---

**Update:**

```
jQuery('#RegionLink').on('hidden', function() {
    $('#CityLink').removeData('modal');
});
```

Comment: Приведённый вами пример относится скорее к Bootstrap 3 http://stackoverflow.com/a/18459248/5381547

Comment: Да это самый банальный вариант который я естественно пробовал!

Comment: @ДмитрийГвоздь Он не дает нужного результата?

Comment: @NikitaSmith Вам не понятен смысл моего комментария?

Comment: @ДмитрийГвоздь Смысл понятен, просто данный вариант работает в моем случае, и я не понимаю почему у вас не получается тоже самое.

Comment: @NikitaSmith http://m.petovod.ru/ Расширенный поиск, выбираем любой регион, потом выбираем город, далее выбираем другой регион и при выборе города, увидем что города из того региона, который был выбран ранее. Просто вызовы аякс сложно продемонстрировать в примере на данном сайте, может можно как то но я незнаю как.

Comment: В module.js в самом низу закоментированы варианты которые я пробовал.

Comment: @ДмитрийГвоздь Я посмотрел, и написал обновление в своем посте, все работает, единственная проблема в том, что у вас производится загрузка контента второго окна после выбора в первом (до его закрытия), перенесите данную подзагрузку для второго окна после закрытия первого. И все будет окей.

Comment: @NikitaSmith Я не понял к сожалению "суть проблемы", что значит *у вас производится загрузка контента второго окна после выбора в первом (до его закрытия)*

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47727/discussion-between-nikita-smith-and--).